# Bad request using passport-local-mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport-local, passport.js

I'm trying to build in authentication to a small webapp using passport, mongodb, mongoose, express and the passport-local-mongoose plugin. I am being returned a `bad request` when trying to log in a user. I am able to register a user and get the data into the DB.

How do I move forward to debug this with error handling? The docs for passport and passport-local-mongoose seems light (and I'm a bit of a noob).

App.js

```
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

var User = require('./models/user.js')
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

//passport.use(new LocalStrategy(UserSchema.authenticate()))
// use static serialize and deserialize of model for passport session support
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// Connect to Mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/users')
```

Registration route (gets data to the db, but fails to redirect)

```
// Register a user to the DB
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
  let firstName = req.body.firstName
  let lastName = req.body.lastName
  let username = req.body.email
  //let password = req.body.password
  let homeAirport = req.body.homeAirport

  User.register(new User ({
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    username: username,
    homeAirport: homeAirport
  }),
    req.body.password, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.render('register', {
          user: user
        })
      }
      // both of these works
      passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
      function(req, res, next) {
        res.redirect('/');
      }
  })
})
```

Login Route (returns a bad request)

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

User Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

// Define the scheme
var User = new Schema ({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  homeAirport: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  }
})

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User)
```

Comment: How did you get it fixed? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for the late reply! I too faced a problem like this. The problem was not with passport-local-mongoose, it was with passport. It expects the http request to contain the fields username and password. So if you are using email to register, it responds with bad request.

To fix this, change the userNameField as shown below

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
  },User.authenticate()));
```

Hope It Helps

Answer (score 1):

I also had to add it to the schema, like so:

```
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
usernameField : "email"});
```